# How can I detect when the Cache has completed refreshing after a call to RefreshCache on the AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

**Context**
I am writing code to move files to an S3 bucket which is accessed through a file storage gateway. I know that the uploaded files will not appear until a RefreshCache is performed to update the directory in the file gateway.

**Issue**
My code needs to update links in an application to point to the files through the FileGateway share path, but I need to be absolutely certain that the gateway has refreshed and the files are accessible through it before updating the links.

So  I need to wait until the cache has completed refreshing before proceeding with my code to update the links. I'm not entirely sure how to know when the refresh is compete when calling the AmazonStorageGatewayClient.RefreshCache API method.

**Questions**
1. Is the refresh completed when the AmazonStorageGatewayClient.RefreshCache call returns from the API?
2. If not, is there a way to detect in my code when it *IS* done?

**Things I've considered**
Set up a SNS notification through CloudWatch when the gateway is refreshed (still unclear if that is fired only after the refresh). Using a lambda might work here, but that is a bit impractical because this code is running as a service outside of the AWS environment.

Comment: Why not upload the files to s3 thru your gateway? Then there would be no need to refresh the cache - it would already know about those files.

Comment: The reason I am going directly to S3 is that the gateway has become somewhat of a bottleneck. I was hoping for better throughput.